# How to read Image.network memory and get image file

Tags: flutter, dart

Example: `child: Image.network('${this.url}',`

I need this for download image from memory. and how to we access this image.network memory ?

why do i need this Because I want to download the images without sending a query again.İmportant for me.

Comment: Don't use `Image.network`. Make the request yourself and use `Image.memory`.

Comment: Hi . The question asked has some problems. Your request is not clear! Do you need the images to be stored somewhere after receiving them so that they don't need to be requested again?
Or do you need to display a picture of the asset in the ui?
Please specify your request accurately and with more explanation.
It is recommended to read this guide to create a good question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: my question  Image.network('${this.url}', this code working and showing image. how we access this read from memory ?